# Linux VM showing incorrect Space in OS

Tags: linux

I have create one VM guest (on esxi) , OS Ubuntu 16 server. I assigned it 900 GB but I am seeing only 200 GB of disk space.

```
root@XXX-log:/temp# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  900K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   92G   94G  50% /
tmpfs                              7.9G  8.0K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  146M  764M  16% /boot
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
root@XXX-log:/temp#
root@XXX-log:/temp#
root@XXX-log:/temp#
root@XXX-log:/temp# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 920 GiB, 987842478080 bytes, 1929379840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2C824CE0-94E5-4515-B28D-8FA40983CFF5

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 1929377791 1927276544  919G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What seems wrong here & how to rectify? Kindly advise

Comment: Your logical volume `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` has been created with a size of 200 GiB. You can increase that if you need to.

Comment: Ok finally I sorted by using below CMD. Thank you

lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv